# Java generic inheritance "unchecked cast"

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, design-patterns, factory

I've implemented a simple system of payment processing using java generics. It compiles and works at runtime, but i confused by the "unchecked cast" warning.

```java
enum PaymentType {
    CARD, SAVED_CARD
}

interface PayData {
}

class CardPayData implements PayData {
    private String cardNumber;
    private String cvc;
}

class SavedCardPayData implements PayData {
    private String cardId;
}

interface PayService<T extends PayData> {
    void pay(T payData);
}

class CardPayService implements PayService<CardPayData> {
    @Override
    public void pay(CardPayData cardPayData) {
        // i need concrete class CardPayData here
    }
}

class SavedCardPayService implements PayService<SavedCardPayData> {
    @Override
    public void pay(SavedCardPayData payData) {
        // i need concrete class SavedCardPayData here
    }
}

class PayServiceFactory {
    private CardPayService cardPayService = new CardPayService();
    private SavedCardPayService savedCardPayService = new SavedCardPayService();

    public PayService getService(PaymentType paymentType) {
        if (paymentType.equals(PaymentType.CARD))
            return cardPayService;
        else
            return savedCardPayService;
    }
}

class PaymentProcessor {
    PayServiceFactory payServiceFactory = new PayServiceFactory();

    public void serveRequest(PayData payData, PaymentType paymentType) {
//        here i have 'unchecked cast' warning
        PayService<PayData> payService = (PayService<PayData>) payServiceFactory.getService(paymentType);
        payService.pay(payData);
    }
}
```

Any attempts to move away from such warning lead me to compiltation errors. For example i've tried to return generic type from my factory method, and received nothing but compilation error:

```java
// return generic
public PayService<? extends PayData> getService(PaymentType paymentType) { ... }
```

```java
 public void serveRequest(PayData payData, PaymentType paymentType) {
        PayService<? extends PayData> payService =  payServiceFactory.getService(paymentType);
// error here:
// pay (capture <? extends PayData>) in PayService cannot be applied to (PayData)
        payService.pay(payData);
    }
```

Comment: `getService` can only return `PayService<?>`. Don't forget the wildcard, or it is a raw type. And then you've got the problem that `payData` might not be of the correct type. Basically, this approach can't be type safe.

Answer (score 1):

The design of your classes is inherently type unsafe. Specifically, the `serveRequest` method:

```
public void serveRequest(PayData payData, PaymentType paymentType) {
    PayService<PayData> payService = (PayService<PayData>) payServiceFactory.getService(paymentType);
    payService.pay(payData);
}
```

There is no way of enforcing that the runtime type of `payData` is compatible with what `payService.pay` expects. Depending on `paymentType`, `getService` could return `PayService<Anything>` at runtime, so `payService.pay` could expect any type at runtime. Because the type that `payData` should be can only be known at runtime, you can't enforce it at compile time.

The best you can do is to put a `SuppressWarnings` and make `payData` generic:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends PayData> void serveRequest(T payData, PaymentType paymentType) {
    PayService<T> payService = (PayService<T>) payServiceFactory.getService(paymentType);
    payService.pay(payData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. You said that there is no way of enforcing that, so does this named 'Type erasure' ?

Comment: @IlyaPechenkin Type erasure simply refers to the fact that at runtime, there is no generics at all. The generic types all get "erased" and turned into casts. For example, at runtime `payService.pay` will accept an Object` as parameter and then it will cast the parameter to whatever type is appropriate. I don't think your issue is very related to type erasure.